# How to visualize GAM results with contour & tile plot (using ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr, gam, mgcv

I would like to make a contour plot with `ggplot2` by using `gam` results. Below is a detailed explanation of what I want:

```
#packages
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)  
#prepare data
df <- data.frame(x = iris$Sepal.Width,
                 y = iris$Sepal.Length,
                 z = iris$Petal.Length)
#fit gam
gam_fit  <- gam(z ~
                  s(x) +
                  s(y),
                data=df,na.action = "na.fail")
```

To predict z values based on the `gam_fit`, I found a way from https://drmowinckels.io/blog/2019-11-16-plotting-gamm-interactions-with-ggplot2/

```
#predict z values
df_pred <- expand_grid(
  x = seq(from=min(df$x), 
              to=max(df$x), 
              length.out = 100),
  y = seq(from=min(df$y), 
              to=max(df$y), 
              length.out = 100)
)
df_pred <- predict(gam_fit, newdata = df_pred, 
                      se.fit = TRUE) %>%  
    as_tibble() %>% 
    cbind(df_pred)
gg <- ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = fit)) +
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=x, y=y))+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu")+
  geom_contour(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, z = fit), colour = "white")
print(gg)
```

This give me a below plot
[image]

My goal is removing tile and contour at where there are no measured x-y points. For example, there is no measured points around the top-right & top-left corners of the plot.

I wonder if `mgcViz` can achieve this, but it requires including x & y as an interaction term as below (also I am not sure how to add measured points on the below figure):

```
library(mgcViz)
gamm_fit2  <- gam(z ~
                   s(x,y),
                data=df,na.action = "na.fail") #,REML=TRUE
b <- getViz(gamm_fit2)
plot(sm(b, 1))
```

[image]

I think `df_pred` may not the best format to achieve my goal, but I am not sure how to do this. I would be grateful if you give me any solution with `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get something more akin to how `mgcv::plot.gam()` and *mgcViz* produce their plots for something like this, you need to identify pairs of covariates that lie too far from the support of your data. The reason we might prefer this over say clipping the predictions to the convex hull of the observations is that some mild extraxpolation beyond the data is probably not too much of a violation of the fact that splines have penalties that apply over the range of the data only. From a more pragmatic view, and this is something shown in the Anderson's Iris data used in the example, there are regions of the covariate space where we would have to interpolate that lie as far as, if not further from, the support of the data than point we might extrapolate to.

*mgcv* has a function for doing this called `exclude.too.far()`, so if you want total control you can do, reusing code from @jared_mamrot's excellent answer (modified a little)

```r
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("mgcv")

# prepare data
df <- with(iris, data.frame(x = Sepal.Width,
                            y = Sepal.Length,
                            z = Petal.Length))
#fit gam
gam_fit  <- gam(z ~ s(x) + s(y), data = df, method = "REML")

df_new <- with(df, expand_grid(x = seq(from = min(x), to = max(x),
                                       length.out = 100),
                               y = seq(from = min(y), to = max(y), 
                                       length.out = 100)))

df_pred <- predict(gam_fit, newdata = df_new)
df_pred <- tibble(fitted = df_pred) |>
  bind_cols(df_new)
```

Now we can find out which of our rows in the grid we're predicting at represent covariate pairs that are too far from the support of the original data. What `exclude.too.far()` does is transform the pairs of covariates in the prediction grid to a unit square, with [0,0] representing the coordinate (min(x), min(y)), and [1,1] the coordinate (max(x), max(y)). It transforms than original covariate data onto this unit square also. It then computes the euclidean distance between each point in the grid (on the unit square) and each row in the observed data (projected on to the unit square).

Any observation that lies `> dist` from a node in the prediction grid is then identified to be excluded as lying too far from the support of the data. `dist` is the argument that controls what we mean by "too far". `dist` is specified in terms of the unit square, so the maximum any two points can be on the unit square is

```r
r$> dist(data.frame(x = c(0,1), y = c(0,1)))                                    
         1
2 1.414214
```

The default in `plot.gam` and IIRC in *mgcvViz* is `dist = 0.1`. If we do this for our example

```r
drop <- exclude.too.far(df_pred$x, df_pred$y, df$x, df$y, dist = 0.1)
```

`drop` is now a logical vector of length `nrow(df_pred)`, with `TRUE` indicating we should exclude the observation pair.

Using `drop` we can set `fitted` to `NA` for the points we want to exclude:

```r
df_pred <- df_pred |>
  mutate(fitted = if_else(drop, NA_real_, fitted))
```

Now we can plot:

```r
df_pred |>
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fitted)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = NULL)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu") +
  geom_contour(aes(z = fitted, fill = NULL), colour = "white")
```

producing

[image]

You can do this a bit more easily using my *gratia* package (IMHO), but the general idea is the same

```r
# remotes::install_github("gavinsimpson/gratia") # need's dev version
library("gratia")

# prepare data
df <- with(iris, data.frame(x = Sepal.Width,
                            y = Sepal.Length,
                            z = Petal.Length))

# fit model
gam_fit  <- gam(z ~ s(x) + s(y), data = df, method = "REML")

# prepare a data slice through the covariate space
ds <- data_slice(gam_fit, x = evenly(x, n = 100), y = evenly(y, n = 100))

# predict
fv <- fitted_values(gam_fit, data = ds)

# exclude points that are too far
drop <- too_far(ds$x, ds$y, df$x, df$y, dist = 0.1)
fv <- fv |>
  mutate(fitted = if_else(drop, NA_real_, fitted))

# then plot
fv |>
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fitted)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = NULL)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu") +
  geom_contour(aes(z = fitted, fill = NULL), colour = "white")
```

Answer (score 4):

There might be a package designed to handle this task, but if you can't find the right 'tool' for the job one option is to draw a polygon around the 'points' and colour everything outside the polygon grey, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)

#prepare data
df <- data.frame(x = iris$Sepal.Width,
                 y = iris$Sepal.Length,
                 z = iris$Petal.Length)
#fit gam
gam_fit  <- gam(z ~
                  s(x) +
                  s(y),
                data=df,na.action = "na.fail")

df_pred <- expand_grid(
  x = seq(from=min(df$x), 
          to=max(df$x), 
          length.out = 100),
  y = seq(from=min(df$y), 
          to=max(df$y), 
          length.out = 100)
)
df_pred <- predict(gam_fit, newdata = df_pred, 
                   se.fit = TRUE) %>%  
  as_tibble() %>% 
  cbind(df_pred)

ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = fit)) +
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=x, y=y))+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu")+
  geom_contour(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, z = fit), colour = "white") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.9, 4.5),
                  ylim = c(4, 8))
```

[image]

```r
# Get the 'hull' around all of the dots
hulls <- df[chull(df$x, df$y), ]
# Get the 'edges' of the frame, starting at the first hull point
edges <- data.frame(x = c(4.1,4.5,4.5,1.9,1.9,4.5),
                    y = c(5.2,4,8,8,4,4),
                    z = NA)
# Combine
draw_poly <- rbind(hulls, edges)

# Draw the plot, and overlay the gray polygon
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = fit)) +
 geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu") +
  geom_contour(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, z = fit), colour = "white") +
  geom_polygon(data=draw_poly, aes(x=x, y=y), fill = "grey")
```

[image]

```r
# Without the points
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = fit)) +
#  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu") +
  geom_contour(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, z = fit), colour = "white") +
  geom_polygon(data=draw_poly, aes(x=x, y=y), fill = "grey")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Here's another example using the [concaveman package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/concaveman/index.html) to calculate the concave hull:

```r
library(ggforce)
#install.packages("concaveman")
library(concaveman)

border <- concaveman(as.matrix(df[,1:2]), concavity = 2)
edges <- data.frame(V1 = c(4.5,4.5,1.9,1.9,4.5),
                    V2 = c(4,8,8,4,4))
draw_poly <- rbind(border, edges)

ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = fit)) +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu") +
  geom_contour(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, z = fit), colour = "white") +
  geom_shape(data=draw_poly, aes(x=V1, y=V2), fill = "grey",
             expand = unit(-0.05, "cm"))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = fit)) +
 # geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu") +
  geom_contour(data=df_pred, aes(x=x, y=y, z = fit), colour = "white") +
  geom_shape(data=draw_poly, aes(x=V1, y=V2), fill = "grey",
             expand = unit(-0.05, "cm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>